# Go back to another or old Activity from a fragment in an activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I have looked for this but, can't seem to find the answer that I need.

So, my scenario is, I have activityA that starts activityB using Intent. Then activityB sets up some values in a bundle and starts a fragment using fragment manager. Now, I want to go back to *activityA* when a button is click. I also want to pass some variables from the Fragment to activityA. How do I do this?

Currently, I just start just the activityA again by using intent with some bundle of data passed in from the fragment. This is not good, because I am restarting activityA again. I just want to go back like using OnResume() or something similar, so that my old data is still there in activityA again.

Thanks

Comment: you can start both activity b and fragment with intents and "startForResults"

Comment: `startActivity()` with an appropriate `Intent` is a valid solution. You might also want to look at [manipulating the Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html). I'm not very familiar with this part of the Android API, so I can't offer any guarantees. Hopefully it will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either call finish like you would do from an Activity but like so:

```
getActivity().finish();
```

Or you can start the Activity and recall the previous one from the stack:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), activityA.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Comment: Of course, the OP can also set the any extras to pass to the activity. (Will this cause a call to `onCreate()` or just `onResume()`?)

Comment: Nevermind...the documentation you linked answers my question.

Comment: onCreate is only called when the Activity is first created. With this flag you are displaying an already created instance of the Activity, if there is one. According to the Android Documentation: "If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent." I assume the onStart() will be called though as the onStop should have been called previously.

Comment: The documentation continues with "If it has declared its launch mode to be "multiple" (the default) and you have not set FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP in the same intent, then it will be finished and re-created; for all other launch modes or if FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP is set then this Intent will be delivered to the current instance's onNewIntent()." So there are situations where the activity will be recreated and `onCreate()` called.

Comment: I don't really understand that sentence. What does  "declare "multiple" (the default) mean? and what is same intent? in my case FragmentA or B?